# Anchor Element moves in the DOM

Tags: html, dom, anchor, element

My source looks like this:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Southwest Pumps: Fire Pump Sales and Services</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"     href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/3fe3352e0f.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat"     rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="/sales/new">Create New Job Entry</a>
<table class="table table-striped table-dark">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Customer Name</th>
<th>Job Name</th>
<th>Last Edited</th>
<th>Editor</th>
<th>Link to Job</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="tbody">
<a style="display:block" href="/sales/5b428cd7b87ffb0aa03c94f2">
<tr>
<td>Customer</td>
<td>Job</td>
<td><input type="hidden" id="inputdate0" value="Tue Jul 10 2018 21:21:47     GMT+0000 (UTC)"></input></td>
<td>LeslieSmooth</td>
<td><a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"     href="/sales/5b428cd7b87ffb0aa03c94f2">Link</a></td>
</tr>
</a>
<a style="display:block" href="/sales/5b429ff7b87ffb0aa03c94f6">
<td>Customer</td>
<td>Job</td>
<td><input type="hidden" id="inputdate1" value="Tue Jul 10 2018 21:22:27     GMT+0000 (UTC)"></input></td>
<td>LeslieSmooth</td>
<td><a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"     href="/sales/5b429ff7b87ffb0aa03c94f6">Link</a></td>
</tr>
</a>
<a style="display:block" href="/sales/5b42b24eb87ffb0aa03c94f8">
<tr>
<td>Customer</td>
<td>Job</td>
<td><input type="hidden" id="inputdate2" value="Tue Jul 10 2018 21:23:40     GMT+0000 (UTC)"></input></td>
<td>LeslieSmooth</td>
<td><a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"     href="/sales/5b42b24eb87ffb0aa03c94f8">Link</a></td></tr>
</a>
<a style="display:block" href="/sales/5b44f07d7945fe0e5388efd6">
<tr>
<td>Customer</td>
<td>Job</td>
<td><input type="hidden" id="inputdate3" value="Tue Jul 10 2018 21:30:46     GMT+0000 (UTC)"></input></td>
<td>LeslieSmooth</td>
<td><a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"     href="/sales/5b44f07d7945fe0e5388efd6">Link</a></td>
</tr>
</a>
<a style="display:block" href="/sales/5b43b048601191087dc0b618">
<tr>
<td>Customer</td>
<td>Job</td>
<td><input type="hidden" id="inputdate4" value="Tue Jul 10 2018 21:33:22     GMT+0000 (UTC)"></input></td>
<td>LeslieSmooth</td>
<td><a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"     href="/sales/5b43b048601191087dc0b618">Link</a></td>
</tr>
</a>
<a style="display:block" href="/sales/5b44bc6b7945fe0e5388efd2">
<tr>
<td>Customer</td>
<td>Job</td>
<td><input type="hidden" id="inputdate5" value="Mon Jul 09 2018 18:58:16     GMT+0000 (UTC)"></input></td>
<td>LeslieSmooth</td>
<td><a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"     href="/sales/5b44bc6b7945fe0e5388efd2">Link</a></td>
</tr>
</a>
<a style="display:block" href="/sales/5b450a6c7945fe0e5388efd8">
<tr>
<td>Customer</td>
<td>Job</td>
<td><input type="hidden" id="inputdate6" value="Tue Jul 10 2018 21:33:34     GMT+0000 (UTC)"></input></td>
<td>LeslieSmooth</td>
<td><a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"     href="/sales/5b450a6c7945fe0e5388efd8">Link</a></td>
</tr>
</a>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<!-- jQuery CDN -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-    hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS CDN -->
<script     src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
</script>
<!-- Genaric Scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/script.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

But the DOM moves all my anchor elements above the TABLE and it ends up looking like this for some reason.

My goal is to make the whole row of the table an anchor element that links to a particular database id. I am totally clueless as to what is going on. Any help is appreciated!

```
...<div class="container">
<a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="/sales/new">Create New Job Entry</a>
<a style="display:block" href="/sales/5b428cd7b87ffb0aa03c94f2"></a>
<a style="display:block" href="/sales/5b429ff7b87ffb0aa03c94f6"></a>
<a style="display:block" href="/sales/5b42b24eb87ffb0aa03c94f8"></a>
<a style="display:block" href="/sales/5b44f07d7945fe0e5388efd6"></a>
<a style="display:block" href="/sales/5b43b048601191087dc0b618"></a>
<a style="display:block" href="/sales/5b44bc6b7945fe0e5388efd2"></a>
<a style="display:block" href="/sales/5b450a6c7945fe0e5388efd8"></a>
<table class="table table-striped table-dark">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Customer Name</th>
<th>Job Name</th>
<th>Last Edited</th>
<th>Editor</th>
<th>Link to Job</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="tbody">
<tr>...
```

I'm using Bootstrap. And I'm generating the anchor tags with NodeJS/Express and using EJS.

JIC my EJS code looks like this:

```
...<div class="container">
<a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="/sales/new">Create New Job Entry</a>
<table class="table table-striped table-dark">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Customer Name</th>
<th>Job Name</th>
<th>Last Edited</th>
<th>Editor</th>
<th>Link to Job</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="tbody">
<% for (var i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) { %>
<a href="/sales/<%= jobs[i]._id %>" style="display: block;">
<tr>
<td><%= jobs[i].customer %></td>
<td><%= jobs[i].name %></td>
<td><input type="hidden" id="inputdate<%= [i] %>" value="<%=     jobs[i].lastEdited %>"></input><span class="date-class" id="spandate<%= [i] %>">    </span></td>
<td><%= jobs[i].editors[jobs[i].editors.length - 1].username %></td>
<td><a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="/sales/<%= jobs[i]._id     %>">Link</a></td>
</tr>
</a>
<% } %>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>...
```

Comment: It's not valid HTML to have `a` as a child to `tbody`.  You're going to need to do something like add an `onclick` event to the row instead.

Comment: Simple as that eh?! I'll give it a try! Thank you!

Comment: Oh my god that was so easy... Thank you a million times!